# JS Switch Statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm trying to use two switch statements to interpret some info from an AJAX call.

The code looks like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/8124qnog/2/

Basically, I want the first loop to check through the array "roleArray" and assign the value to a variable "role". It can have four different values:

L, S, J, or A.

I then want the next switch statement to check the value of 'role' and see whether it is an L, S, J or A, and assign values to variables.

When I try to do `console.log(aFactor)` for example, I get an undefined value, which seemingly means my loop isnt running or switch statement isnt coded properly.

Can I do this?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Code:

```
            //ALGORITHM START
            for (i = 0, i < 10; i++;) {
                switch (roleArray[i]) {
                    case "DUO":
                        //assumes top lane duo
                        role = "L";
                        console.log(role);
                        break;
                    case "DUO_CARRY":
                        //assumes bot lane adc
                        role = "A";
                        console.log(role);
                        break;
                    case "DUO_SUPPORT":
                        //assumes bot lane support
                        role = "S";
                        console.log(role);
                        break;
                    case "SOLO":
                        //assumes mid or top solo
                        role = "L";
                        console.log(role);
                        break;
                    case "NONE":
                        //assumes jungle, check lane
                        role = "J";
                        console.log(role);
                        break;
                    default
                        role = "L";
                        break;
                }

            switch (role) {
                case "L":
                    aFactor = 1.00; //kills
                    bFactor = 0.66; //assists
                    cFactor = 0.75; //deaths
                    dFactor = 0.80; //cs
                    eFactor = 0.20; //jungle cs
                    fFactor = 0.55; //counter jungle cs
                    gFactor = 0.50; //cc time
                    break;
                case "A":
                    aFactor = 1.00;
                    bFactor = 0.10;
                    cFactor = 1.00;
                    dFactor = 1.00;
                    eFactor = 0.20;
                    fFactor = 0.30;
                    gFactor = 0.33;
                    break;
                case "S":
                    aFactor = 0.20;
                    bFactor = 2.00;
                    cFactor = 0.33;
                    dFactor = 0.10;
                    eFactor = 0.33;
                    fFactor = 0.55;
                    gFactor = 2.00;
                    break;
                case "J":
                    aFactor = 1.00;
                    bFactor = 1.50;
                    cFactor = 0.75;
                    dFactor = 0.33;
                    eFactor = 1.20;
                    fFactor = 1.60;
                    gFactor = 1.00;
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: It's customary to add your code directly to the question so that it stands without a visit to a 3rd party site.

Comment: To point out a few typos in your JSFiddle code - 1) You are missing close brackets on both for loops. 2) Your loop has `i > 10` instead of `i < 10`. 3) In your switch statement, `default` needs to be `default:`. Hope this helps.

Comment: JSHint complains about the same things. Please make sure your code is valid before posting.

Comment: Just to note that it's kind of pointless to use two switch statements here.  You can just combine the cases in the first switch that set the same role to use common case code and then put the code for that case in the first switch.  There appears to be no need for two switch statements.  Also, it is not clear what the point of the `for` loop is since you will just end up with the result from the last switch statement executed, no accumulation of results via the `for` loop.

Comment: `i` should be `var i` to prevent variable clashes. This is why the whole loop only runs once.

Comment: I added the whole code. I excluded most of it initially becasue I didnt want to overwhelm people with the unnecessary parts.

Comment: Also, I see i < 10... I don't know where you're seeing i > 10

Comment: `for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { /* code */ }` - That's the syntax you want. You mostly have syntax errors in your code, that's the problem.

Comment: Seems to complicated, should be more like this -> **https://jsfiddle.net/8124qnog/11/**

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to figure it out but your code didn't make sense. First of all be sure of closing your blocks properly.

Secondly, put colon  after default like

```
default: 
// your code
```

Plus, why would you do that ?

```
for (i = 0; i > 10; i++) {
                    var pvpFactor = ((aFactor * killArray[i]) + (bFactor * assistArray[i])) / (cFactor * deathArray[i]);
                    var pveFactor = ((dFactor * csArray[i]) + (eFactor * jungleCSArray[i]) + (fFactor * counterJungleCSArray[i])) / (gameTimeArray[i]);
                    var auxFactor = (gFactor * crowdControlArray[i]);

                    var rawHMC = (0.8 * pvpFactor) + (0.4 * pveFactor) + (2.5 * auxFactor)

                    var HMCarray = [];
```

Declaring the variable in a for loop for no reason ? The variables are going to be valid only for i = 9 . Why would you put it in a loop ?

Answer (score -1):

//SYNTAX:

```
        switch(Expression){
            case 1:
                condition;
                break;
            case 2:
                condition;
                break;
            case 3:
                condition;
                break;
            case 4:
                condition;
                break;
            case 5:
                condition;
                break;
            case 6:
                condition;
                break;
            case 7:
                condition;
                break;
            case 8:
                condition;
                break;
            case 9:
                condition;
                break;
            default:
                last Condition;
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you further explain how that would solve the problem? I don't really get how that applies to the question as it already uses the correkt switch-syntax. Furthermore I doubt that the `condition;` is actually a condition but just a instruction. Have a nice Day.